# How to have JTable staying on the edited cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

If someone edit the cell content of a JTable and press enter, the content is modified and the table selection moves to the next row.

Is that possible to **forbid the JTable to go to the next row after a cell edition**?

The reason is that my program synchronize some other widgets on cell selection using a ListSelectionListener, and I do not want to have the next row selected after editing the current cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default binding for <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the `Action` named `selectNextRowCell`. To override the entry in the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` input map, you'll need to supply a `doNothing()` `Action`, as suggested in [*How to Use Key Bindings: How to Make and Remove Key Bindings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto).

Comment: Great suggestion! The complete work to do is to add a call to table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing(); in the actionPerformed(...) method. Without this call, the cell remains in edition mode when the user press enter.

Comment: Good point; see also [Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how exactly to do this, but I would look into [ActionMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ActionMap.html).  You should be able to either modify or replace the Action that is mapped to the 'Enter' key.

Good luck!